# drupal form filler for QA

Tags: jquery, drupal, forms, macros, fill

hey, i got a form in drupal that  has 50 fields and im getting sick each time to debug and fill the forms , is tehre a utility / jquery script to do random lorem lipsum or somthing like that?

Answer (score 1):

In your form definition, you could loop through all the fields and put a default value in them, while debugging. This little snip should handle all text fields.

```
foreach ($form as $key => $field) {
  $form[$key]['#default_value'] = 'test';
}
```

If you have a lot of select fields, you could add an options for that too. All you need to do, it to remote those lines when done.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ff addon from http://lastpass.com
Better choice ;)

foreach is not acceptable because probably we could to use select lists or integers' fields

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, there are some add-ons you can use to fill out the form automatically. Search the add-ons page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=form+autofill&cat=all&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

I strongly invite your to install a module called devel generate which is inside the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). Devel generate helps you to generate node by filling your forms with lorem ipsum. ;)

Comment: but devel generate will create the nodes by itself, I think amirash needs to have control before submitting I suppose.

Comment: `to do random lorem lipsum or somthing like that?` I don't think so :)